# IOS swift project integration with Facebook : tons of warnings

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication, compiler-warnings

I am using Facebook Login for my app. I added pods and all those steps, but when I compile the project, I got over 150 warnings. 
in Podfile:

platform :ios, '10.2'
 .......
   pod 'FacebookCore'
   pod 'FacebookLogin'
   pod 'FacebookShare'

Compile warning example:
/Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.m:133:17: Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior

Has anyone got tons of warnings after adding pods of Facebook to your IOS swift project?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code and associated errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line to your Podfile:

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Then run `pod install`

This will prevent warnings from your Cocoapods from appearing within your app. Since you are not likely able to do anything about them, then why see them?

Of course, warnings can lead to bigger issues (after all, XCode is telling you something is wrong), so use as you see fit.